# woocommerce post meta display

Tags: php, woocommerce, meta

In WooCommerce we want to display a notice on the single_product_summary when a custom meta field is true. The application is for disabled users to purchase eligible products without (VAT) tax.

The custom meta: disability_exemption is created in a plugin that handles the checkout.

This is the code I am trying in a custom plugin, but this applies the exemption flash on all products whether the meta is true or false. I only want it to show when the meta is true.

```
function jdp_add_vat_exempt_product_flash() {
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'key', true );  {
    echo '<span class="onsale">VAT EXEMPT</span>';
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'jdp_add_vat_exempt_product_flash' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'jdp_add_vat_exempt_product_flash' );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!